# Graph Theory, Hamiltonian Cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Let $a, b \geq 3$ and let $G$ consist of two complete subgraphs $G_a$ and
$G_b$ that share exactly two vertices. How many Hamiltonian cycles are in $G$?

I was close!
As answered below, $(K_a - 2)! * (K_b - 2)!$

The $-2$ is because the $2$ connecting points are somewhat fixed to bridge the two

Answer (score 2):

Let $u$ and $v$ be the two shared vertices.  Any Hamilton cycle (viewed as a subgraph and not as a walk) would be the union of a $(u,v)$-Hamilton path in $K_a$ and a $(u,v)$-Hamilton path in $K_b$.  Using the Multiplaction Rule, the number of such cycles is $(a-2)!\cdot (b-2)!$